# PhoneGap Cordova Media Plugin - How to integrate/install?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, plugins, media

I have been searching everywhere and trying everything, but I just can't seem to be able to use cordova's Media plugin. (e.g  `var sound = new Media("sound.mp3");` )

I've tried everything and can't seem to get it to work.
Please put me out of my misery and give me a step by step instruction on how to do this. I have android sdk and gethub installed already along with a bunch of other things.

Most of the things I see are, " Installation: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media`" THATS IT. Specially the ones with the stupid $ symbol which is completely unrecognized.

..thank you in advance :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first double check your work: [Step1](http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/create-cordova-project.html), [Step2](http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/build-cordova-project.html)
Then, to add media plugin to your project you need to:

```
(in app/res/xml/config.xml)
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
</feature>


(in app/AndroidManifest.xml)
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

[More info](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_media.md.html)

And this is a code sample of how to use it ([source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/blob/b2e92f93964f76bbec667dfdfe15caec435932b6/doc/index.md))

```
// Play audio
//
function playAudio(url) {
    // Play the audio file at url
    var my_media = new Media(url,
        // success callback
        function () {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function (err) {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        }
    );
    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}
```

Finally, you can call the playAudio('path/to/file.mp3') function within your code (after device got ready).

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(Media);
    /* call function here */
}
```

Comment: Thank you Amin for your quick and detailed response! Unfortunately I have all these added already. The only difference your code made was the app didn't crash on computer's website(still no sound though) but still doesn't work at all on my android note 4. It also still has the Uncaught ReferenceError: Media is not defined error.

Comment: @VardanBetikyan did you add the cordova script tag?

Comment: Hello AtanuCSE, thank you for the response.
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

This line? Into my index.html? It was already there.

Comment: You **do** need to add the plugin to your project though, did you do that? You need to open a command prompt window in your project directory and then type, as you said in your question, `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media`, and then build your Android project. The Phonegap/Corodova folks are big fans of OSX/Linux, and the command prompt on those platforms is "$", so that's why you see that all the time in the docs. On Windows it'll be ">". You don't type the "$" at the command prompt, the "$" **is** the command prompt.

Comment: @VardanBetikyan if the Media is not defined you either use it before deviceReady (check my updated answer) or you don't add the plugin correctly.

Comment: Hi Mike Dailor.

I realized how silly I was, I started adding the codes without the "$" and build afterwards(thank you for the brief history on the linux lovers :)) Although still, no change.

@Amin I think my index.js comes with the "deviceReady" built in (see response to AtanuCSE)

Comment: @VardanBetikyan You need to call the function on deviceready. Try the code at the end of my answer and let me know what heppens.

Comment: @Amin Program stopped working altogether. Although still gives the Media error.

Is it necessary to create a new app via
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld ??

Comment: @VardanBetikyan Something is wrong. Not a bad idea to create a fresh App and test from the beginning.

Comment: Just tried.. same old errors :(

There is also a Phonegap.js and Cordova.js "File not found", idk if this is significant?
The Cordova.js file is in the android directory, but none in the main www.

Comment: @Amin I did.. A few times actually. Same thing. Not working.
My initial program was working fine with everything. In javascript I was using the simple var sound = new Audio(); It worked wonderfully in browser, but not android. Everything in android, from clicking to drawing images worked, only sound didn't. Is there perhaps an alternative? I really only need the sound, the rest works fine :/
I appreciate all the help you've given me Amin.

Answer (score 1):

when you're at the root of your cordova project, `cordova plugin ls` should result in your seeing `org.apache.cordova.media 0.2.16 "Media"` in the list.

If not, the plugin hasn't been added...

`cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media` should do it.

And then be certain you wait for onDeviceReady before you try to use the Media object--else it'll be undefined.

Comment: Hello Tawpie, thank you for your response.

I ran both lines and "Media" & the "File" were both on the list. Still getting same Media is not defined error :/

Although I haven't tried your "onDeviceReady" method, how do I accomplish this?

I have this code already built in in my main js file, is this it?

Comment: var app = {
 // Application Constructor
initialize: function() {
this.bindEvents();
},
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
...ect

Comment: The key thing here, and the reason it works on a browser and not on your Note, is that actual devices take some time for Cordova to get them ready to use the plugins--browsers on computers are generally quite quick. When you try to call a plugin method before Cordova has it ready, the method will be undefined and this is what's happening to you. When Cordova has finished getting the plugins ready, it fires a device ready event as a signal to you that the plugin methods are "defined". This is what your addEventListener is watching for. (more)

Comment: Try moving `var sound = new Media("sound.mp3");` inside of the onDeviceReady listener's function call as suggested by Amin: `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    var sound = new Media("sound.mp3");
}` Of course, don't try to use your sound object until `typeof sound !== 'undefined'`

Comment: I tried numerous ways, including this. Nothing. Still same error. Re-installed everything too.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your code and the output of `cordova plugins ls`... the plugin does work, we'll get this figured out.